# How do I change the default 'navbar-toggler' button icon in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, hamburger-menu

I've searched everywhere and have tried multiple things, but I just can't seem to get it to work with my code. I'm trying to change the default `navbar-toggler` hamburger button icon in bootstrap and use a custom Font Awesome icon. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Logo Deciding Where To Put It-->
    <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="images/KevinLogo01.png"></a>-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcustom"
      aria-controls="navbarcustom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcustom">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
span.navbar-toggler-icon::after {
color: white;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change it using just CSS, then this snippet could be the answer to your question-

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a03fb08303.js"></script>
<style>
    .navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: none;
    }

    .navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon::after {
        content: "\f0c9";
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #333;
    }
</style>
        
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-custom">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Logo Deciding Where To Put It-->
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="images/KevinLogo01.png"></a>-->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcustom" aria-controls="navbarcustom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-dark" id="navbarcustom">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And if you want to change it using just HTML, then this one could be the answer, delete the span in the `navbar-toggler button` and replace it with font-awesome like this-

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcustom"
      aria-controls="navbarcustom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x text-dark"></span>
</button>
```

Here is a full example in this snippet, lemme know which one helped you or you needed something else.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a03fb08303.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Logo Deciding Where To Put It-->
    <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="images/KevinLogo01.png"></a> -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcustom"
      aria-controls="navbarcustom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x text-dark"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcustom">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto bg-dark">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! The HTML part worked. Would you mind sending jd explaining to me what was wrong with my code? I'm currently in school and trying to learn as much as I can. Thanks again!

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept the answer with upvote.

Comment: Bootstrap-4 used svg `background image` for `<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>` (they did not use `::after`) to prevent that, you have to set the `background-image: none;` which I did in the CSS answer of this question. You didn't prevent it, that was your missing puzzle here.